# Google App Engine Mysql Driver not accepting the JDBC url spring cloud gcp

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-app-engine, spring-cloud-gcp

I am trying to deploy spring boot application on Google App Engine using spring cloud gcp.

When running locally Mysql JDBL Url formed make a successful connection to Cloud Mysql database in Google Cloud Platform. When the application is deployed (appengine:deploy) when the api is hit it tries to make the connection to mysql the url formed is unacceptable my jdbc driver. Throws following exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:google:mysql://pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance/pocketpharmadb
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:330)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
>   at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppEngineWebAppContext.startWebapp (AppEngineWebAppContext.java:175)

How to make the successful connection to database when application deployed?

I tried to hardcode the jdbcUrl in the application.properties. it gives the proxy exception.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/pocketpharmadb?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance&useSSL=false
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pocketpharma.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>PocketPharmaApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PocketPharmaApi</name>
    <description>Api End Points for The Pocket Pharma</description>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.82.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=pocketpharmadb
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/pocketpharmadb?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance&useSSL=false
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/pocketpharmadb?socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&cloudSqlInstance=pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance&useSSL=false

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://pocketpharmaapi123:asia-southeast1:pocketpharmapi-db-instance/pocketpharmadb

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/pocketpharmadb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin123

#spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
#spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

#spring.jpa.show-sql = true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: You seems to not be following the proper JDBC URL format


"
jdbc:mysql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>
"


Check out the official github page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory